# How to animate same object in a different multiple animation settings? - Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I would like to create a multiple animations that they are look the same but with a different settings(Like different duration/ Speed/ Size etc.)

I start to learn about animation in [This guide](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-creating-a-simple-tween-animation--mobile-14898)

So if I look at this example, I want to create a multiple suns (Lets say 10 Suns) that every sun started in different time and position with a different speed.

Is someone know how to do this thing?

**Important thing:**
I need to show a big number of elements (not only 10), so create 10 imageviews with 10 animation is not a good solution.

Thanks!

Comment: if you dont want to create 10 or more ImageViews see this custom Drawable: https://github.com/pskink/PatchworkDrawable

Comment: But in my project the layers are animated and not just an image. The image used for displaying animate object.

Comment: did you read README.md ?

Comment: "Those layers can be transformed with a Matrix (scale, translation, rotation) and **any standard android Animation** can be applied to."

Comment: I read but did not notice that sorry, So i just need to add the library and use it like the example?

Comment: i wouldn call it library, its just one java file